# ASP.NET Telerik AJAX Web Forms Loading Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have an ASP.NET web forms project in which I use telerik controls and AJAX Manager. The problem is here:

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="rAM" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true" DefaultLoadingPanelID="rlp">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rtsSystemsSetup">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <%--<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rtsSystemsSetup" ></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>--%>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rlbSystems">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rlbSystems"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rlbMeasurementTypes">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rlbMeasurementTypes"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="rlp" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

When I have EnableAJAX="true" everything works fine in a production and published environment. However, when I am in debug mode on my local machine, I have to set it to FALSE for some things to work correctly while I am testing. For example, if I leave it to TRUE, when I am trying to get a Listbox to ping the OnSelectedIndexChangedEvent, it does nothing--set Ajax=false, and it works fine. However, I have to change it back before I publish and it works fine in production. Some things though, like bootstrap modal popups, only work when I have AJAX=true. So I am constantly having to reload the page by making this ridiculous change to test different parts of my page.

My CTO makes changes to the project occasionally and he has no issues with this AJAX problem I am having. Has anybody ever ran across this? Is there a server setting on my IIS Express that is wrong somewhere or something in VS I have setup wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `AutoPostBack = "True"` in the ListBox , because after disabling manager under AJAX sending a refresh but if Menager is on the ListBox itself refreshes . This should help. I once had a similar problem

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1" AutoPostBack="" runat="server"></telerik:RadListBox>
```

Comment: I'm currently doing this and it does work when I have AJAX disabled. But I have to enable AJAX for my bootstrap modals to work. :( For what reason, I am unsure.

Comment: The event fires when I turn off the manager when I have AutoPostBack=True, but I have to enable manager to get the modal popup to work so I can actually see the control lol